# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to delete some records in Mysql database laravel view and I got an error called

General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `'user_id'` at row 1 (SQL: delete from `youths` where `id` = 568)"

I tried to fix it by resetting `sql_mode` as follows

```
sql_mode = ""
```

This is my delete query

```
public function delete(Request $request)
  {
      $id = $request->id;
      $youth = Youth::find($id);
      $youth->delete();
  }
```

This is my table structure for youths table
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV4NY.png)

But The error keeps the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: Show your table structure for `youths`.

Comment: yes, please show table structure, then only we can help.

Comment: I updated the question with table structure. And `user_id` is not auto incremented

Comment: you are deleting row in table using ID not using user_id. So, it must be another problem. You can do one thing -> go to mysql run the query and check what you get.

Comment: I got the same error in mysql shell. I have updated my delete query also. Please check it too

Answer (score 0):

The error itself states the issue here

> General error: 1366 **Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id'
>   at row 1** (SQL: delete from youths where id = 568)"

In your `user_id` column value is required to be an integer, if you check the every cell column `user_id` of your table you'll find the issue there. the query itself is correct, its the non integer value in column `user_id` throwing sql error.

Comment: you mean he has string value in user_id field which is supposed to be integer!

Comment: nope it is supposed to null but its not null, its empty

Comment: If it was a string then the error would have been **value: 'some string'**

Comment: Aditya. Data type of `user_id` is int. How its called as string. I checked every rows in table. Couldn't find any string there.

Comment: i am not saying its a string, i am just saying its not an integer, if you insert an integer to user_id row 1, you'll understand.

Comment: user_id needs to be either an integer or NULL, but its empty,

Comment: I tried too many times by changing type and null status. But nothing has been changed.

Comment: I'm sure `user_id` type is int(10). You can see it in table structure. Other thing is how delete query check `user_id` instead of `id` when i try to delete row

Comment: i am not saying your type is wrong, but the column has an empty value, it needs to be null, you can try searching the column for empty value, you need to realise the **empty is not null**, here i reproduced the same error by making a int field empty, https://imgur.com/a/Y9O0Iqe ,

Comment: It could be just one entry in that column, or it could be many entries.